# Phone Link inside web-view in iOS app

Tags: ios, html, safari, swift4

I've an iOS app which has a web-view (using WebKit) which has some contact us information including a phone number. In the app I want my user to be able to click the anchor tag and the app would ask the client if he want to call that number or not. I wrote in my html the following in the head.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
```

I also tried all the following anchors structures with no luck.

```
<a href="tel:+x-xxx-xxx-xxx">+x-xxx-xxx-xxx</a>
<a href="tel:xxx-xxx-xxx">xxx-xxx-xxx</a>
<a href="tel:(xxx) xxx-xxx">(xxx) xxx-xxx</a>
<a href="tel:(xxx)-xxx-xxx">(xxx)-xxx-xxx</a>
```

I have to click and hold on the anchor tag in order for this dialog to be shown but in Android all what you have to do is just a simple click without the hold. Is that doable in iOS and if so please let know how? [image: what happen when I press and hold on the anchor tag]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after testing for over a week in order to find a solution for that issue. 
Here is the solution. It didn't really matter the phone structure as it mattered the code that I wrote to handle what happens once the user click on it (from the app inside of the web view).
In the class responsible for that (your view controller)

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    // handle it here
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        // print(navigationAction.request.url!)
        // if the URL have tel in it then use the iOS to open it not the webkit
        if (navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString.contains("tel")) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else if (!(navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString.contains(MAINURLNOTTOGOOUTSIDE))) {
            // if the URL is something outside of the one specified in that string "MAINURLNOTTOGOOUTSIDE", open it using the iOS not the webkit
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        let app = UIApplication.shared
        if (navigationAction.targetFrame == nil) {
            if (navigationAction.request.url!.scheme?.contains("tel"))! {
                if (app.canOpenURL(navigationAction.request.url!)) {
                    app.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    // handle if failed to connect to the server
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        var message = ""
        var title = ""
        var button = ""

        if (Locale.preferredLanguages[0].contains("ar")) {
            title = "خطأ"
            message = "تعذر الوصول الى الخادم الرجاء المحاولة في وقت لاحق"
            button = "حسنا"
        } else {
            title = "Error"
            message = "Unable to access server Please try again later"
            button = "OK!"
        }
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: button, style: .default, handler: nil))
    }
    // handle if failed to connect to the server
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        var message = ""
        var title = ""
        var button = ""

        if (Locale.preferredLanguages[0].contains("ar")) {
            title = "خطأ"
            message = "تعذر الوصول الى الخادم الرجاء المحاولة في وقت لاحق"
            button = "حسنا"
        } else {
            title = "Error"
            message = "Unable to access server Please try again later"
            button = "OK!"
        }
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: button, style: .default, handler: nil))
    }
}
```

also don't forget to include the following in the viewDidLoad method

```
self.WebView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and had been scratching my head for about a week. Thanks for your solution!